# Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 (Vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing my project in Vb.net.
my project name is "Bellows".
My front end is Vb.net.
Back end is Ms Access.

i complete my project.
i copy the .exe file from "E:\BellowNet(new)\Bellows\obj\Debug" and put the shortcut into my desktop. now it's running.

similarly i copied my Bellows.exe from another system desktop but it not running.

**How i want to run my Bellows.exe from another systems (maximum 10 systems).**

**Note** : In my system only having Microsoft Visual Studio 2005.
           Remaining system doesn't have.

I put bellows.exe from another system. in that system doesn't having E Drive.
it showing this error

**The application Filed to initialize properly(0xc0000135).  Click Ok to terminate the application**

Similarly I put bellows.exe from another system. in that system  having E Drive.

if i click that Bellows.exe
the login form is open..
and main form is open.
in that main form wen i click button it show the error.

**Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.
If u click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue.
If u click Quit, the application will close immediately.
Could not load file or assembly ‘ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublickeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified**